# Swift how to detect specific String in uilabel

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I would like to add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to label and detect which specific text tapped. 
for instance text on the label is `hi, how are you` And if user tapped `hi` then I would like to detect that and print that text.

I tried like this but can't add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the `element`. I understand because `element` doesn't have that property.

```
  guard let text = textLabel.text? else { return }
        let separateText = text.components(separatedBy: ",")
            separateText.forEach { (element) in
                    let myGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDelete))
                element.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                element.addGestureRecognizer(myGesture)      
      }

  @objc func handleDelete() {
     print(element)
    }
```

How can I achieve what I want? 
Should I take different approach?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Wow, quite interesting task :)

Your approach won't work as String is not UI element and can not be interactable like other UI elements.

One approach could be adding tap gesture recogniser to UILabel and base on tap position. But this will be hard especially when you need to support different languages (some for example have deferent read direction or can have "hi" in different place in text).

Another one could be using `NSAttributedString`. You could add `URL` (via [NSAttributedStringKey link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstringkey/1535719-link)) to attributed string and handle it. Defect of this approach is fact that you have to use `UITextView` as `UILabel` doesn't support url handling.

Simplified code:

```
    func setup(textView: UITextView) {
        let text = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Hi ", attributes: [.link: URL(string: "myDeeplink://textClickRecognizer?text=Hi")!])
        let otherLinkText = NSAttributedString(string: "how are you ", attributes: [.link: URL(string: "myDeeplink://textClickRecognizer?text=how%20are%20you")!])

        text.append(otherLinkText)

        textView?.attributedText = text
        textView?.isEditable = false
        textView?.dataDetectorTypes = .link
        textView?.delegate = self  
    }

    // UITextViewDelegate
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {

        //you should check if link is supported / expected one
       //....

        let components = URLComponents(url: URL, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)!
        let queryItem = components.queryItems?.first!

        print(queryItem?.value)

        return false
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment!! That's cool approach but what I actually want to achieve is that there is label that displays hashtags and if user tap delete button then that label became clickable then I want delete selected tag. How can I achieve this? What I can think of is using collectiveview. Do you have any idea?

Comment: `UICollectionView` sounds good especially when you assume lot of hashtags with scrollable content. If not the `UIStackView` can be even better. For sure one `UILabel` is not good approach for this 

Comment: Right label was not good approach haha. Thank you so much you cleared things up!!